# how do i get single digits from a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, match

im a trying to get each single digit out of a string of random generated charecters and store them in an a array for example :

```
random string  = eejhbf3u4du34uiwe93u8quiwe92oq
```

i want my array to be like this

```
number[0] = 3
number[1] = 4
number[2] = 3
number[3] = 4
number[4] = 9
number[5] = 3
number[6] = 8
number[7] = 9
number[8] = 2
```

the code i have is ...

```
var singlenumbers = randomstring.match(/\d+/);

alert(singlenumbers);
```

any sugestions ?

Answer (score 3):

Use `/g` to match all instances:

```
var singlenumbers = randomstring.match(/\d/g);
```

If desired, you can convert each of the resulting matches to a number with a simple `map` call:

```
singlenumbers = singlenumbers.map(function (i) { return i | 0 });
```

Comment: remove `+` - he wants single digits

Answer (score -2):

```
String.prototype.forEach=Array.prototype.forEach; 
String.prototype.getSingleDigits=function(){
    var arr=[];
    this.forEach(function(e){
        if (!isNaN(parseInt(e))) arr.push(e)
    }); 
    return arr;
};

alert("sdcia298f9384n29n94".getSingleDigits())
```

Comment: That's quite a sledgehammer method :)

Comment: don't use a nuke to kill a sparrow!
Also this solution modifies the default String object, what isn't recommended for default javascript snippets

Comment: Downvotes? Now I'm even farther from getting rid of this question ban.

Comment: This solution is for someone who doesn't wanna use regexp because they keep forgetting how it works so they just gave up on it for the most part (like myself)

Comment: @bukart I modify prototype all the time it's fine.

Comment: @NickManning Yep, modifications of the prototype object are often a "smart" solution, and yep, it works. The problem will occur in future if more and more snippets extend the prototypes of the default objects (!) and than some strange behaviour can't be tracked down. I recommend this book for such cases: http://www.javascriptenlightenment.com/

Comment: @bukart which section of that book exactly? Modifying `String` is no big deal...at least I dind't modify `Object` (but I still think it's okay to modify `Object`).